# Instagram API for DMs

Tags: python, api, python-requests, instagram, instagram-api

I'm making an Instagram Bot to automatically send messages to users using python requests,
When I check network in developer tab while send a message, there is no any request generated by Instagram,

Can anyone please help me to find API of DM or anything which can help me??

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a bit more detail on what you've already done?

You can find a decent tutorial on the Instagram Python API at https://rapidapi.com/blog/instagram-api-python/.

Comment: I wanna scrape all followers of a profile and send them a message,
I'm using requests library in python,

I didn't understand which method Instagram using to send a message